# Inherited enum redefinition

Tags: java, enums

It is more complex than it sounds, but I think I am obliged to try something like it. I want to make an abstract parent class with a prototyping of an enum (I want to declare the enum with only one value probably that will be the default unitialized one and also declaring a couple of methods that I will be using from the subclass), then I want to class that will extend the abstract parent to actually intialize the very same enum (I know that this practically hides the parent enum) so that the kid class will define a set of items inside the enum, but keep the methods probably.

I do not know much about this level of abstraction so I will now describe the nature of my problem, in case there is a more practical solution:
I have a bunch of files that contain classes that implement a lot of commands based on enums. (e.g. class1 implements Observer has an update method that uses an enum-based switch to decide what command was picked, same applies for the other classes) I now want to abstract this whole thing in a way that I have an enum variable with the exact same name in all classes (e.g. CommandSet) so that I can have a generic method inside the parent that will be able to print a help list to my system using the inside methods of the enum. Now I know I can rewrite the exact same method in every class, but I want to abstract it so that others can keep on extending the library I am making!

Hopefully I am not too confusing or too confused and somone can help me! :)

Edit: Here is an idea of the code (Probably not right):

```
  public abstract class Commands{
    enum CommandSet{ 
        // empty command, placeholder
        null_command ("command name", "command description");
        // the Strings used for name and description
        private final String name;
        private final String description;
        // constructor 
        CommandSet(String name, String description){
            this.name=name;
            this.description=description;
        }
        // get parameters
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public String getDescription(){
            return description;
        }
    }
    public void showHelp(){
        for (CommandSet i : CommandSet.values()) {
            printf(i.getName(),":",i.getDescription());
        }
    }
}

public class StandardCommads extends Commands implements Observer{
    // I want to change the enum here, just changing the values so that null_command ("command name", "command description") will get removed and I will add a dozen other values, but keep the methods that the parent had
    // update inherited from Observer
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object object) {
        // I want the commands inside the switch cases defined inside this class's enum 
        switch(CommandSet.valueOf(String.valueOf(object)){
            case command1: doStuff1();break;
            case command2: doStuff2();break;
            ...
            case commandN: doStuffN();break;
        }
    // other methods
    void doStuff1(){
        ...
    }
    ...
    void doStuffN(){
        ...
    }
}

public class NonStandardCommads extends Commands implements Observer{
    // Another set of commands here for the enum keeping the same methods it had in the parent

    // update inherited from Observer
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object object) {
        // Other set of commands inside this class used in the switch statement
        switch(CommandSet.valueOf(String.valueOf(object)){
            case Zcommand1: doStuffz1();break;
            case Zcommand2: doStuffz2();break;
            ...
            case ZcommandN: doStuffzN();break;
        }
    // other methods
    void doStuffz1(){
        ...
    }
    ...
    void doStuffzN(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't do that.

Java Enums run out of gas very quickly & definitely, when you want to add/extend more definitions or instantiate the enum instances, at a later time. (eg load them from database, configure them in an instance method, not just statically.)

Behaviour/ or logic in Java enums is kinda limited too -- you can define & set properties, but only what's statically initializable, and logic seems basic (you end up mainly just comparing references or ordinals, with the other defined enum constants).

**What you can do:**

You *can* implement an ancestor Command or AbstractCommand class, with a integer Code, and then subclass it to define concrete values/ additional codes/ load or configure instances, etc.

For further benefit, you get efficient switch & despatch (by Code) plus the ability to define further details/properties, instantiate commands as-needed, etc.

Essentially, this is how you used to define an Enum before Java supported them. Though you may be using them as *value objects*, rather than strictly static.

**My expertise:**

I've done extensive compiler & type-system work, tried enums for file-types and associated data/behaviour.. explored the outer limits, and reached the definite boundaries.

I also like being able to instantiate & return a new UnknownFileType("") as an *answer*, too. Enums can't do that.

**Example:**

(We'll despatch by String, not int -- since your code appears to be using Java 7. This makes command resolution easier, than requiring both a syntactical "name" and an internal integer "code".)

```
public static class Command {
  protected String code;
  protected String desc;
  public String getCode() {return code;}
  public String getDesc() {return desc;}
  public Command (String code, String desc) {
    this.code = code;
    this.desc = desc;
  }
  public String toString() {return code;}
}

public class StandardCommands {
  public static Command READ = new Command("READ", "read a record");
  public static Command CREATE = new Command("WRITE", "create a record");
  public static Command EDIT = new Command("WRITE", "modify a record");
}
public class FurtherCommands extends StandardCommands {
  public static Command LIST = new Command("LIST", "list all records");
}

public class QueryCommands extends FurtherCommands {
  public static class QueryCmd extends Command {
    protected String search;
    public String getSearch() {return search;}
    // constructor..
  }
  public static QueryCmd QUERY_EXAMPLE = new QueryCmd("QUERY", "example", "query for specified string");


  public static QueryCmd createQuery (String search) {
    return new QueryCmd( "QUERY", search, "query for specified string");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you spend a moment on giving me a sample on how to make an enum-like class as you suggest? May be a hint! :)

Comment: @Spiritios -- I'd appreciate a vote up?  I've probably spent 20 minutes now, trying to pass on what I know & answer your question :)  Thanks!

Comment: What about resources? Isn't that significantly heavier than an enum in terms of memory? (So if I had enums with 20000 commands wouldn't they spend much less memory than 20000 OBJECTS of this class?)

Comment: No different, enum's an object too.  Good programming practice in Java is no longer about trying to avoid object instances at the high level, anyway -- and many of the Command instances can be static, as shown above. Equivalent to an enum when static, more flexible when not.

Comment: Still it gives me trouble to use it in a switch with code as String, probably gonna turn it into an int to improve it.

Comment: Yes, 'code' property as int is best for a switch statement in Java 6. That's the way it's done in ANTLR parser or Eclipse JDT compilers. Java 7 can switch on string.. internally it uses hashcode. (Still can't handle nulls, though.) Thanks!

Comment: 1) You already got a vote up, of course I appreciate the time you spent. 2) I know but String in switch statements has already caused me some funny errors some time back, so I refrain from using it generally. 3) Btw is there any more resource-efficient way to implement what I am looking for here? Just in case it gets too heavy after implementing too much functionality...

Answer (score 3):

Impossible: Java enums can neither extend another class nor be extended themselves.

They can however implement interfaces. Perhaps you can use that to your advantage.

There is something else about enums that may help you: enums are not [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). You could change field values of the enums, however that would change them for the whole JVM.

Another approach maybe to pass your subclass instances into a method of the enum and have the enum use your subclass as a [call back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) to get different functionality out of an enum for a different user of the enum.

Comment: No I do not mean to extend enum, I mean that the second class will inherit an enum from the abstract parent. But can I redefine it partially?

Comment: So you mean to implement an interface in the enum like `enum Commands implements someInterface{ //codehere}`

Comment: @Spiritios Exactly. I have trouble following your question: It seems too long-winded. Can you condense it down and make it clearer? Maybe with a code fragment of how you would like the code to look (even if not valid syntax), so we get a better idea of what you want

Comment: Check out the question I have provided a thorough example of what I am looking for, with as much commenting as I could! :)